# ReferrenceError: __moduleName is not defined Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, components, systemjs

So I find this trick that we can use __moduleName so that systemjs will be able to tell where we currently are and we don't need to specify the whole folder path.

Component

```
@Component({
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    selector: 'app-customer',
    templateUrl: 'customer.component.html'
})
```

app.d.ts

```
declare var __moduleName: any;
```

I already declare __moduleName to be a global variable but the console still says referrence error. Any suggestions?

Comment: same issue. ON a side note using the module.id version from older angular2 demos almost works but it keeps rendering the parent components in the child.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the format you register transpilation. 'system' registers [__moduleName](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md#systemjsimportmodulename--normalizedparentname---promisemodule) variable to use relative paths to the module. This is the node module (the js transpiled file), not the angular module (the bundle of node modules). Node also has a default that can be used if you use 'commonjs' format, the [module.id](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_id).

You can check your settings of tsconfig.json :

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "module": "amd | umd | system | commonjs | es6 | es2015 | none",
  ...
}
```

}

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html